# MS Access SQL DISTINCT taking a very long time

Tags: sql, ms-access

A rather plain SQL query that joins 6 tables, with a simple Where clause completes in 2 seconds as shown here (omitting specifics for clarity):

```
Select (tab1.col1 & ',' & tab1.col2) as COMPUTED_COLUMN
From <join clause for 6 tables>
Where tab1.col3=4 AND tab2.col1=1 AND tab3.col1=21 AND tab1.col2<>-1
```

Great! Completes in 2 seconds on database where tab2 has 120k records and returns 280 records.

Now, I just want to count DISTINCT values for COMPUTED_COLUMN. I know the answer is 140.

So I think that adding

```
Select DISTINCT (tab1.col1 & ',' & tab1.col2) as COMPUTED_COLUMN
...
```

will do that nicely. It takes 9+ minutes!

So I removed DISTINCT and instead added

```
GROUP BY (tab1.col1 & ',' & tab1.col2)
```

after the Where clause. It also takes 9+ minutes!

So, clearly this is not the right way to accomplish what I want to do.

What am I doing wrong? Or, what is the correct way to count Unique Values for the combination of tab1.col1 and tab1.col2?

Comment: Twice you say you want a count of unique values, but both code samples return a list of unique values. Which are you after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd do well to perform your initial select, and then insert the results into a temp table. From there, processing your `DISTINCT` command should be super quick. Don't forget to delete / clean-up the temp table when you're done.

Comment: You are correct! After trying the others below, this works quite well. The Distinct query from the TEMP table works instantly! Thanks everyone that contributed!!!

Comment: EXTRA CREDIT!? The new method takes 0.04 seconds compared to 10 minutes! Why?

Comment: @JJJones_3860 it would be hard to give you a definitive answer without seeing your schema and indexes, but the odds are it's a combination of Access handling computed columns poorly and a lack of indexes in some way, shape, or form.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest first using your current query with its `WHERE` clause, and then subquerying that to generate the computed column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 & ',' & col2 AS COMPUTED_COLUMN
FROM
(
    SELECT tab1.col1, tab2.col2
    FROM <join clause for 6 tables>
    WHERE tab1.col3 = 4 AND tab2.col1 = 1 AND tab3.col1 = 21 AND tab1.col2 <> -1
) t;
```

The idea here, if this works/helps, is that we can first throw away many records in the subquery, and then need to only aggregate few records in the outer query.

Comment: I like this better than my answer, and it should work equally well.

Comment: Thanks, but that query is still running after 1 minute! So, even if it finishes in less than 9+ minutes, the performance is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Do the data selection in a subquery which includes `GROUP BY tab1.col1, tab2.col2` --- that will return only distinct combinations of those two fields, and should be fast with indexes on both those fields as well as the `JOIN` 
 and `WHERE` clause fields.

Then do your concatenation to derive `COMPUTED_COLUMN` in the outer query.

```sql
SELECT sub.col1 & ',' & sub.col2 AS COMPUTED_COLUMN
FROM
(
    SELECT tab1.col1, tab2.col2
    FROM <join clause for 6 tables>
    WHERE tab1.col3 = 4 AND tab2.col1 = 1 AND tab3.col1 = 21 AND tab1.col2 <> -1
    GROUP BY tab1.col1, tab2.col2
) AS sub;
```

Comment: Thanks, but your subquery, exactly as shown above, simply running by itself is still running after 1 minute. So this solution would not work. If I remove the GROUP BY, that subquery finishes in 3 seconds.

Comment: Are tab1.col1 and tab2.col2 indexed?  Is either of them Memo (Long Text) datatype?

Comment: Not indexed. Both are Data Type "Number".

Comment: Please index both fields and try the approach I suggested again.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Interruptions. Applied individual indices to both columns (Duplicates OK). Reran the subquery above. Still running after 2 minutes.

Comment: Nuts.  In that case, Haney's suggestion looks more appealing.